# Нет протоколов ws:// и wss:// при вызове stream_get_transports в php

Tags: php, linux

Не могу открыть web socket в PHP потому что нет протоколов WS и WSS!
Возвращается следующая ошибка

> Unable to find the socket transport ws - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Когда выполняют `stream_get_transport` возвращаются следующие

```
0 => "tcp"
1 => "udp"
2 => "unix"
3 => "udg"
4 => "ssl"
5 => "sslv3"
6 => "tls"
7 => "tlsv1.0"
8 => "tlsv1.1"
9 => "tlsv1.2"
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так вебсокеты не являются транспортным протоколом, не?

Comment: Еще как являются, по крайней мере в api slack`a адрес сокета указан через wss. И куча примеров на js показаны через эти протоколы!

Comment: И-и... что? Транспортным для WS и WSS является TCP, а вы, похоже, просто используете не ту функцию. На этом, впрочем, зона моей РНР-компетенции заканчивается.

Comment: Получается для ws это tcp, а для wss какой?

Comment: Тоже TCP. А сверху него TLS.

Comment: Я пробовал требовало порт, указывал 443 вообще все висло (таймаут вылетал)

Comment: WebSocket это протокол поверх TCP. для php бывают разные библиотеки для работы с ним. Собственно гугл больше информации даст чем я. И хоть ws это протокол апгрейд в который происходит из http, обычно он web-серверами не поддерживается и по этой причине висит на других портах, а не на 80 и 443

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо!

В итоге да, получилось через этот пакет сделать:
https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php